# Can anyone tell me: How this code is working?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

```
n=int(input("Please Enter Number: "))
a="*"
k=" "
for i in range(n,-1,-1):
    for j in range(i+1):
        k=" "*((n+1)-j)
    
    print(k+(a*i)+a+(a*i))
    k=" "
```

This code should print a downward triangle and, yes, it is giving the correct output.

But the problem is that, when I try to understand the code, it is mathematically wrong. How is the space increasing, as it should be zero according to the code written.

[image: down-word triangle with spaces]

Comment: That code is unnecessarily complicated. All you need in your top loop is `print((k*(n-i))+(a*(i*2+1)))`.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop doesn't do anything **visible** (like printing output) inside the loop and only the final value of `k` is used; that final value will be at the end of the given range, so will be `i+1`. (All other, intermediate, `k` values will simply be overwritten on the subsequent run(s) through that inner loop.)

Thus, the value of `k` printed on each execution of the *outer* loop will be from `k = " "*((n+1)-i+1)`, which is equivalent to `k = " "*(n+2-i)`. Further, as the `i` is **decreased** (by 1) on each of those outer loops, the number of spaces will **increase** (correctly).

(Note, also, that your two `k=" "` lines are pointless, as those values will also be either overwritten, on the first/next run through the outer loop, or ignored, on the final run through that loop.)